# What's the difference between tp and teleport?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Snapshots for 1.10 introduced teleport command feature for /execute. What is its difference to the current 
tp? I heard it has something to do with "*relativity*" (~)

Comment: As of 1.13, these commands now do the same thing.

Comment: @ppperry Which one?

Comment: @allex2003super Which what?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:**

As mentionned by ppperry in the comments, this answer is no longer valid I'm afraid.

> Tp is now a simple alias of Teleport /tp is now an alias of /teleport
> (much like /w, /msg and /tell). /teleport has been simplified a bit,
> to avoid ambiguity.
> [Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.13)

---

**Old Answer:**

- When running a /tp command and using relative coordinates, the coordinates are calculated **from the entity focused** by the command
- When running a /teleport command, relatives coordinates are
  calculated **from the entity who is executing** the command

Source with exemple and screenshots (in french) : [fr-minecraft.net/news-minecraft-1820](http://fr-minecraft.net/news-minecraft-1820-minecraft-prerelease-1-10-pre1-le-test-complet.html)

exemples :

```
/execute @e[name=Zomb2] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[name=Zomb1] ~ ~3 ~
```

will teleport the zombie "Zomb1" 3 blocks above the position of "Zomb2" (as it was Zomb2 that executed the command)

```
 /teleport @e[name=Zomb1] ~ ~3 ~
```

will teleport the zombie "Zomb1" 3 blocks above you

Comment: you're welcome, I just added concrete exemple

Comment: That's great man!

Comment: So, /tp executes relative to the execution location, while /teleport executes relative to the affected entity's position?

Comment: @DanielG the other way around